AuthRetryableFetchError with Supabase and Flutter
For four days I have been having trouble connecting to Supabase servers. I have a free plan for the development of my project with Flutter, but for four days, the authentication service has stopped working, I no longer have access to the database from Flutter even though I am well connected to the Supabase board and my project is functional.
This code :
await supabase.auth.signInWithOtp(phone: phoneNumber.value);
Is giving this error: AuthRetryableFetchError, even though my network is working fine.

What should I do?
Can upgrading to a Pro plan resolve my issue?

I need help please
I'm getting getting data from Flutter but only Authentication is no more working.
I tried to update my project, consult the logs, run tests from Flutter but it doesn't work.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I finally found the error.
I had deleted a "subscriptions" table from my database even though there were associated triggers.
SOLUTION

I then searched for the triggers associated with this table

SELECT proname AS function_name, prosrc AS source_code FROM pg_proc JOIN pg_namespace nsp ON pg_proc.pronamespace = nsp.oid WHERE prosrc ILIKE '%subscriptions%' AND nspname = 'public';
I found the function that was using this table
2. then I deleted it and everything is ok now.
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS handle_new_sub() cascade;

Thank you community.

Awesome bro, you save few days of headache for me !
